# ArcGis Multipatch not close 3D after projection

Tags: 3d, gis, spatial, arcgis

I create multipatch for simple 3D shapes as Cone, Pyramid and part of cylindre. To do that I use meters (RGF93) and need to store it in my Database in WGS84. I tried to do projection (RGF93 to WGS84) of multipatch but it appears that after projection it's no more close 3D (so impossible to do geoprocessing).
Does anyone know why?
Is it possible to create multipatch in WGS84 with meters ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tried a lot of things and read many documentations, I finally found two things :

- First of all there is a Resolution and a Tolerance parameter on featureClass that allow to adjust precision of isClosed operation.You can see it on ArcCatalog in properties of featureClass : [image]
- Then I figured out that even with a better tolerance the 3D object was still not close3D in WGS84.

It seems that geoprocessing has issues with unprojected coordinate systems. I tried to create Shape in projected system, store it in WGS84 and then project back to the projected coordinate system and now it's perfectly close3D.
:)

So remember to work in projected coordinates system when you want to use geoprocessing.